# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH after reinstall openssl package

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, glassfish

I removeв openssl package to install downgrade version(I needed) but unfortunately I didn't expect that my ubuntu 20.04 crushed. I fixed login issue and installed appropriate openssl version. But still have one problem - can't open my localhost project with https -

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error in chrome and 404 in mozilla

I tried

1. replace with new self signed SSL cert in my glassfish server
2. downgrade min TLSv to 1 in mozilla
3. Add MinProtocol = TLSv1 and CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1 to my openssl.cnf.

There is what curl https://localhost:8082 --tlsv1 --verbose returns:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8082...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8082 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

And openssl s_client -connect localhost:8082 returns:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=0 C = US, ST = ST, L = City, O = Home, OU = OU, CN = localhost
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = ST, L = City, O = Home, OU = OU, CN = localhost
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = ST, L = City, O = Home, OU = OU, CN = localhost
   i:C = US, ST = ST, L = City, O = Home, OU = OU, CN = localhost
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = US, ST = ST, L = City, O = Home, OU = OU, CN = localhost

issuer=C = US, ST = ST, L = City, O = Home, OU = OU, CN = localhost

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: MD5-SHA1
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1319 bytes and written 427 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 64995AAB0681A8646E93EC3A7E47B3BB5937BABFB2D6EAE1449983CD875F5CF7
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 640255936456AC2258537245FE1A28A151CB187E0540A13F67A096629475ED36B661947917B7972B4B9D528B07CC4750
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1687771819
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
read:errno=0
```

**Somebody knows what to do except reinstall ubuntu from scratch?
Maybe there are some openssl dependencies which I should install?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find the reason. Just replace all glassfish files and now it works. Chrome browser still shows an error but I can use mozilla.